# Joomla 3.7 - HTML Code is replaced by __RL_Protected ---

Tags: joomla-3.7

I recognised on my page the mod_login is not shown correctly:
In the original php (modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php (line 33) files it looks like

```
 <input id="modlgn-username" type="text"
 name="username" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18"
 placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME'); ?>" />
```

But in the rendered version in Chrome, Firefox and Edge it is show in this

```
 <div class="controls">
 <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">
            <span class="icon-user hasTooltip" title="Benutzername"></span>
                <label for="modlgn-username" class="element-invisible"> 
                     Benutzername
                </label>
            </span>
    <!-- ___RL_PROTECTED___PGlucHV0IGlkPSJtb2RsZ24tdXNlcm5hbWUiIHR5cGU9InRleHQiIG5hbWU9InVzZXJuYW1lIiBjbGFzcz0iaW5wdXQtc21hbGwiIHRhYmluZGV4PSIwIiBzaXplPSIxOCIgcGxhY2Vob2xkZXI9IkJlbnV0emVybmFtZSIgLz4KCQkJCQk=___RL_PROTECTED___ -->
  </div>
  </div>
```

The above shown input tag was replaced by this **RL_PROTECTED** Comment.
Does anybody know remove this behavior? Or is there a plugin missing?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't double post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983163/joomla-3-7-html-code-is-replaced-by-rl-protected

Comment: Sorry, I removed the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, updating Regular Labs's Email Protector plugin to the latest version (4.1.6) fixed the issue for me.
Thanks n.h. for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

You probably have an extension from [Regular Labs](https://www.regularlabs.com/) installed.

Just make a search inside plugins. Go to *extensions->plugins* and search, for instance, per 'regular'.

If any, they should be listed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me very well. Thank you very much